# Fail to set height constraints of UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, constraints

I create a xib file and it includes a `UITextView`, I add a height constraints for UITextView. When the UIViewController load the xib view I want to change the UITextView height based on the text height. I create an IBOutlet named`heightConstraints` for the height constraints and `textView` for UITextView. I set it in

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubview {
    CGFloat height = [self getTextHeight:self.textView];
    self.heightConstraints.constant = height;
    [self.textView layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

But it does not change the height of UITextView. Can anyone help?

Comment: Let debug and print out the value of textview size height before and after update constant.

Comment: It does not change

Comment: I find my problem, it is because I set the top and bottom anchor of the textView, if I remove the setting will work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubview {
    self.heightConstraints.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height;
    [self.textView layoutIfNeeded];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement like this, you are required to confirm the `UITextView` delegate method to change it's height dynamically

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    [self updateTextViewSize:textView];
    return YES
}

- (void)updateTextViewSize:(UITextView*)aTextView{
    CGFloat height = [self getTextHeight:aTextView];
    self.heightConstraints.constant = height;
    [self.textView layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (CGFloat)getTextHeight:(UITextView*)aTextView{
    /*
     calculate frame based on the text and return
     */
}
```